# My desktop computer has broken after overclocking

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, bios, graphics, overclocking

I overclocked my desktop from 3.6 to 4.2 in the BIOS, it's an ASUS motherboard and it's an AMD Radeon Graphics card. Now when I turn on my desktop, the screen is just blank. It's not the screen, when I unplug the screen it says 'Not connected to visual output'. I've tried putting the graphics card in the three other slots available on the ASUS board, and I've even replaced the graphics card with another graphics card from my roomates computer and tested that in two other slots. When I boot it up, I don't even see the BIOS.

Any identification of this problem? Is it common? Any quick solution? It is an ASUS motherboard so it shouldn't break like this, but it can't be the graphics card as I've tested it with another one.

Board: Sabertooth 990 FX

No post noise don't even show post.

12 months old

AMD Bulldozer 8 core 3.6 processor

No lights blinking on motherboard

Comment: It would help MASSIVELY to mention the specific model, and the specific changes you used to overclock it. I'd also look at the blinking lights on the motherboard and report what they say. I do believe asus has a fairly sane, safe automatic software and bios based overclocking method

Comment: does it beep / POST?  how old is the motherboard, does it look healthy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the specific model Asus motherboard, I can only speak in general terms.  You need to clear the CMOS.  With most motherboards you do this by a jumper on the motherboard itself.

[image]

^^ that is an image of one from an Asus board 
[image]

^^ that is a more generic image, that clearly designates it as a CMOS related jumper

You would set the jumper from the position it is always in, to the only other position available, power the system, power it off, and return the jumper to the original position.

Again, this is a **very** generic solution.  As to your specific motherboard, you should examine the user manual found at [Asus' support site](http://support.asus.com).  You look up your specific motherboard, you download the manual for your language, and you find the section dealing with clearing the CMOS.  Depending on the motherboard that you have, there might even be a specific power button action that will clear the overclock settings, so that you don't have to actually clear the CMOS... however, again I don't know anything about your specific motherboard.  If yours does have this feature it would be in your motherboard's manual.

Clearing the CMOS will return the overclock settings back to the factory specs, so if your overclock is responsible for the system not booting, it should boot normally after you clear it.

The fact that it is an Asus motherboard has nothing to do with it "breaking".  You may have simply overclocked it beyond the capability of your CPU.  This can happen with every board manufacturer.

Comment: some new computers also have a bios reset button. Asuses don't seem to, but its worth looking for

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Some of them do (might be on the back panel), others have other buttons that do similar things, like the MemOK button.